# Questions about differents way to run airflow and the way to add Airflow Provider Package

Tags: airflow

I have some questions concerning the starting of Airflow.

To start Airflow I use 3 differents ways:

**1st way:**
I install airflow with the command `pip install apache-airflow`
I initialize the database with `airflow initdb`
I start the webserver with the command `airflow webserver -p 8080`
I can go to `localhost:8080` to access the UI

**2nd way:**
I start airflow with the `airflow standalone` command

**3rd way:**
I download the following docker-compose.yaml `curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.0/docker-compose.yaml'`
I create the directories dags, logs, plugins and the env file with the following commands

```
mkdir -p ./dags ./logs ./plugins
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env
```

Then I run the command `docker-compose up airflow-init`

I start the services with `docker-compose up`

So I have several points I don't understand:

1. If I understood correctly in case 1 and 2, I install and start airflow locally. What is the difference between the commands `airflow webserver -p 8080` and `airflow standalone`?
2. In case 2, we run the `docker-compose up airflow-init` command which will start the airflow-init service. Then we will run the `docker-compose up` command to start all the other services. Is it not possible to launch directly `docker-compose up` and not launch `docker-compose up airflow-init`? At first sight I would say no, because in the following docker-compose .yaml

we have in some services:

```
depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```

for example in the service `airflow-triggerer` we have :

```
airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```

3. Finally I would like to create a Spark connection in airflow. To do this I first install the apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark plugin with the command `pip install 'apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark'`. When I run the command `airflow providers list` I see that the plugin is added. What I don't understand here is that when I access the UI via the commands `airflow webserver -p 8080` or `airflow standalone` I can see that in Admin>Connections>Connection type, that I have the Spark plugin. But when I access the UI via the command `docker-compose up` I don't see the Spark plugin.

Is it because the command `pip install 'apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark'` installed the plugin only in the local airflow? If so, how can I install the plugin also on the containerized airflow?

Thank you so much for your helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between the commands `airflow webserver -p 8080` and `airflow standalone`?

`airflow standalone` is a all-in-one command which init the db, creates the user, and run the webserver, the scheduler and the triggerer, it's similar to the following bash script (but all in the same process):

```bash
airflow db init

airflow users create \
    --username admin \
    --firstname admin \
    --lastname admin \
    --role Admin \
    --email admin@example.com

airflow webserver --port 8080

airflow scheduler

airflow triggerer
```

And by calling them separately you can choose the service you want to start, you can restart a service without affecting the other, and you can run them in different hosts (if your DB is accessible for all the hosts).

> Is it not possible to launch directly `docker-compose up` and not launch `docker-compose up airflow-init`?

Since all the service have `airflow-init` service as a dependency, docker will run the service `airflow-init` and waiting it until it finishes successfully before starting the other tasks, so you can just run `docker-compose up`

> Is it because the command pip install 'apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark' installed the plugin only in the local airflow? If so, how can I install the plugin also on the containerized airflow?

Yes, by executing this command, you install the lib locally, if you want to have it in docker compose, you need to build your own image and use it in the docker compose

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.0
RUN pip install 'apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark'
```

Build the image:

```bash
docker run -it my_airflow_image:2.5.0 .
```

Run docker compose up with your image:

```bash
AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME=my_airflow_image:2.5.0 docker-compose up
```